# ASP MVC Controllers and parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have my first development ASP MVC site and now need to extend it. I have defined a number of Controllers to satisfy the following :

~/Helpers

~/Templates

~/Profiles

What I need now is for the URL to have a parameter in it. So,

~/Helpers/PN

~/Helpers/AD

~/Helpers/TEL

All need to use the same view, passing a parameter of "PN","AD" or "TEL".

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a viewmodel that wraps the individual models and create a partialview that is typed to that viewmodel.   Then  your individual views can render that partial view.

Answer (score 0):

In your Controller, in the Index Action method, Add the parameter. Then you may set necessary property values to your ViewModel object and pass that to your View

```
public class HelpersController
{
    public ActionResult Index(string id)
    {
        YourViewModel objVM = new YourViewModel();
        objVM.Mode = id;

        return View(objVM);
    }
}
```

Assumiung you have a ViewModel called "YourViewModel" which you will use in your View

And Your View will be some thing like this

```
@model YourViewModel
<div >
  You are coming from @Model.Mode 
</div>
```

Now you can call it like any of this

```
yoursitename/Helpers/PN 
yoursitename/Helpers/TEL
yoursitename/Helpers/AD
```

Make sure you validate what comes as a parameter before directly using that.

Comment: Not sure why but this does not seem to be working. I am getting 404s when I set the parameter.

Comment: Yes, the Index works fine on its own (http://localhost:52858/Helpers) , but gets a 404 if I add the parameter (http://localhost:52858/Helpers/TN)

Comment: I have just the default route definition. From the research I have done this seems to be where the problem lies.